# Catch number - Regex - in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

could anybody help me to catch only the number here, there may be 2-3-4 digits number. In this example it is 2 digits.
Thanks in advance!

Balance due: 77 EUR

Comment: What do you mean by "catch" in Notepad++? It is best to tell us what you tried, what you got and what you expected.

Comment: Do you really need this: [0-9]+?

Comment: I want to get only the sum. In that case - 77. That is all

Comment: Where is your try? This is a very basic starting point of almost all tutorials.

Comment: But no i want the word in front of the sum to be "Balance due:" and at the end to be "EUR". And if there are more than one space between words to ignore them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
Balance due: \d{2,4} EUR
```

You get a match for these:

Balance due: 77 EUR

Balance due: 128 EUR

Balance due: 1000 EUR

But not for these:

Balance due: 10001 EUR

Balance due: 9 EUR

Balance due:  EUR